# Solving for $z$ in $\log z = 5i$

Tags: complex-analysis

What in the heck does this mean? $\log z = 5i$ I understand what how the log works, but I don't have a base? I assume that means the base is irrelevant for finding $z$, but that is very strange...

---

$Log_x a=b\implies x^b = a$

Here no base $x$.

Well lets see, $\log z = 5i = (0,5)=5e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}$ Now I am totally lost.

Well I could take the log: $$\log\log z = i\times\frac{\pi}{2}\log 5e$$

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues here. The first, and easiest, to sort out: when dealing with complex numbers, it's safe to assume that $\log$ denotes the logarithm to base $e$. In fact, in "higher mathemathics" it is uncommon to deal with logarithms to other bases.

Secondly, the complex logarithm is **not** well-defined. In fact,
$$
\log z = \ln|z| + i\arg z
$$
where $\arg z$ is **any** argument of $z$. To get a well-defined $\log$, we need to choose a "branch", i.e. to specify which argument to choose. The most common way to get something well-defined, is to take the *principcal branch*, i.e. to choose the value of $\arg z$ such that $-\pi < \arg z < \pi$. (This would make $\log z$ undefined on the negative real axes.)

Hence, if your $\log z$ denotes the principal branch, your equation doesn't have any solutions. (Since $5 > \pi$.)

On the other hand, if your $\log z$ denotes the "multi-valued" version of $\log$, again the equation has no solution. (Since the right hand side is not multi-valued.)

The only way your equation can have a solution is that we have chosen a (somewhat unusual) branch, where $\arg z$ can be $5$. If that is the case, we can verify that $e^{\log z} = z$, no matter which branch we have chosen, so the solution is simply $z = e^{5i} = \cos 5 + i \sin 5$.

Note: you have to be careful when using the usual rules of calculations for $\log$ when dealing with comlex numbers. For example, in general $\log(zw)$ is not $\log z + \log w$. (Unless suitably intepreteted.)

Comment: So if it were $log z = 3i$ We would be able to take a principle root, since our radians are within that bound. Thank you for this detailed answer

Answer (score 1):

The base is of course important in this equation. When it's not specified, it's generally assumed that we're talking about natural logarithms. Although in some circumstances, other bases (e.g. common logarithms with base $10$) are implied, when dealing with complex numbers, I think it's quite safe to assume we're talking about natural logarithms with base $e$.

To solve, take antilogs (exponentiation) of both sides:

$z = e^{5i}$

So the solution is a complex number with magnitude $1$ and argument $5$ radians. It can also be expressed as:

$z = \cos 5 + i\sin 5$, where the angle is in radians.

Answer (score 1):

Where the base is not told it usually means base 10 or base $e$ (more often $e$ is indicated with ln rather than log) so the answer would be $10^{5i}$ or $e^{5i}$ depending on your textbook.